# Polling a simple queue from within another, and filling the first queue from the second queue

Tags: go, queue

In other words, the flow of an event-driven queue:

- poll event queue
- if event found, process event, then next poll cycle
- if no event found, poll data queue
- if data found, push to event queue, start next cycle polling event queue
- if no data found, exit flow

Here is the code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Queue struct {
    stream []string
}

// Next returns first element from stream.
// Returns false if no element is in the stream.
func (q *Queue) Next() (s string, ok bool) {
    if len(q.stream) == 0 {
        return s, false
    }
    s = q.stream[0]
    q.stream = q.stream[1:]
    return s, true
}

func main() {
    // define queues
    events := []string{"event"}
    q1 := &Queue{stream: events}
    data := []string{"data1", "data2", "data3"}
    q2 := &Queue{stream: data}

    // poll first queue
    for e, ok := q1.Next(); ok; e, ok = q1.Next() {
        // nothing in q1
        if !ok {
            fmt.Println("Nothing found in q1")

            // poll second queue
            d, ok := q2.Next()
            if !ok {
                return
            }

            // found d in q2 and append to q1
            fmt.Printf("found in q2 %v\n", d)
            q1.stream = append(q1.stream, d)
            return
        }

        // do some stuff to e ...
        fmt.Printf("found in q1 %v %v\n", e, ok)
    }
}
```

Try it in the playground https://play.golang.org/p/bgJzq2hCfl.

All I get is the element in the first queue.

```
found in q1 event true
```

The code never polls the second queue and append its elements to the first queue. What do i wrong?

If I try

```
// poll first queue
for e, ok := q1.Next() {
    // ...
}
```

the compiler throws

```
tmp/sandbox299553905/main.go:28:25: syntax error: e, ok := q1.Next() used as value
```

Any hints appreciated.

---

**Update:** Here is the solution to the loop.

```
// poll first queue
for e, ok := q1.Next(); true; e, ok = q1.Next() {
    // nothing in q1
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("Nothing found in q1")

        // poll second queue
        for d, ok := q2.Next(); true; d, ok = q2.Next() {
            if !ok {
                fmt.Println("Nothing found in q2. exit")
                return
            }

            // found d in q2 and append to q1
            fmt.Printf("found in q2: %v. append to q1\n", d)
            q1.stream = append(q1.stream, d)
            break
        }
        continue
    }

    // do some stuff to e ...
    fmt.Printf("found in q1: %v. do stuff\n", e)
}
```

You can test it in the playground https://play.golang.org/p/qo0zoBPROe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You exit the loop when it doesn't find anything. Just change your for loop to the following, but note that this makes the loop infinite, so you have to `break` out or `return` to get out.

```
for e, ok := q1.Next(); ok || !ok ; e, ok = q1.Next() {
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you. I will update the final solution in my question..

Comment: @dirk just marking an answer is good enough for that. You shouldn't edit the question with the answer.

Answer (score 2):

After the first iteration, the "increment" happens and this time `ok` is set to `false`. The next step compares `ok == true` (loop termination condition) which is not the case and thus exits.

Now, if I understand correctly what you try to do, I would modify the loop to:

```
// poll first queue
for e, ok := q1.Next(); true; e, ok = q1.Next() {
    // nothing in q1
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("Nothing found in q1")

        // poll second queue
        d, do := q2.Next()
        if !do {
            break
        }

        // found d in q2 and append to q1
        fmt.Printf("found in q2 %v\n", d)
        q1.stream = append(q1.stream, d)
    } else {

        // do some stuff to e ...
        fmt.Printf("found in q1 '%v' ok=%v\n", e, ok)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, just putting `true` there is better than what I did in my answer, but as a one liner answer, I wanted to make sure the var `ok` would get used and not throw a compiler error. Cheers! EDIT: I guess it gets used anyway because it is reassigned in the loop, so `true` wins out a lot better.

Comment: Thank you. I took the ˋtrueˋ from your solution. But @RayfenWindspear was quicker...

Comment: @dirk :) no worries